# Create popup window for each gridview item - Android

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-popupwindow

I'm developing an Android application for a restaurant for an food ordering system.
In my project,I have a `Gridview` ,When click on a `button` on the item in gridview, I want to get a popup window with some textfields,buttons etc.

I got help from [this document example](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-create-popup-window-in-android.html)

the above document example is working alone as single application.it's just an example for creating basic pop-up window.but I need it on `Gridview`.

`my work -->`

instead of above doc's `main.xml` and `PopUpWinndowDemoActivity.java` (it's main activity),
I use my grid_single.xml and it's `implementation file` Grid_single.java.

But it doesn't work for me.When I click on the each item's button,not showing the pop-up window as i hope. So, Please help me to solve this or give me a working example for pop-up window on grid view items. 
I have attached my files with this.
waiting for your help,
Thank you!

Grid_single.java

```
    Button btnClosePopup;
    Button btnCreatePopup;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_single);
        btnCreatePopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addToCart);
        btnCreatePopup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow();
            }
        });


        btnCreatePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                initiatePopupWindow();
            }
        });

    }

    private PopupWindow pwindo;
    private void initiatePopupWindow() {
        try {
            // We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Grid_Single_Popup.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 370, true);
            pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pwindo.dismiss();

        }
    };
```

grid_single.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:id="@+id/grid_single_back"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="24dp" >
    </TextView>
    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Cutomize &amp; Add"
            android:id="@+id/addToCart"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:padding="5sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://codex2android.blogspot.in/2015/11/popupwindow-with-image-and-text-android.html , use this as reference and do the design and implement in adapter ..

Comment: i haven't problem with gridview. my problem is with the pop-up window on gridview..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me, check once

In grid adapter:

```
public CustomGrid(String[] web, int[] Imageid, Grid_single activity) {
    this.Imageid = Imageid;
    this.web = web;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

In getView method of your adapter, keep like this:

```
grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
Button btnPopup = (Button) grid.findViewById(R.id.btnPopup);
btnPopup.setOnClickListener(activity);
```

Grid_single Should implement OnClickListener, and keep like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnPopup:
        initiatePopupWindow(web[grid.getPositionForView(v)]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I kept my sample code at 'http://hastebin.com/qeloveyufu.avrasm' check this and let me know in case any doubts.